# Is there a way to get notified (email, desktop notifications etc.) after my maven clean install is completed in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven build that if successful takes couple of hours. However if it fails abruptly, i have no clue until i get back to IntelliJ and see what happened. Is there a way to get notifications regarding my run/build status from Intellij so i get to follow up right away?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be good to analyse *why* this build takes so long. Then one could find possible speed-ups.

Secondly, making such a build is a job for a build tool like Jenkins, not for IntelliJ. Jenkins can inform you about failed or succeeded builds.

Comment: I am doing apache flink migrations, so i have to build an entire flink proj. I do use jenkins, but that generally is when i make sure i don't have to debug any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since the IDE is a desktop app it notifies about build status on build completion in status bar:
[image]

As for other means of notification I think Fabian's answer is right.